# Is it possible to use Ember-cli-yadda with coffeescript

Tags: ember-cli, ember-cli-addons

So the question is may I set yadda for ember tests to generate .coffee files instead of .js for steps?

Js is ok, but I have ember-cli with coffeescript so it'll be easer for team use one language instead of two

Answer (score 0):

The whole Ember ecosystem is based around using JS instead of coffeescript. There were some early discussions about making blueprints easier for teams to change by default, but there is nothing like that right now.

I'd suggest considering shifting to Aja's as a team instead if that's doable, you'll save yourself a lot of headaches long term ...